# parallel data warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query generated from an aggregate over a sorted partition,

```
SELECT dea.continent, dea.location, dea.date, dea.population, vac.new_vaccinations
 ,SUM(CONVERT(bigint, vac.new_vaccinations)) OVER (Partition BY dea.location ORDER BY dea.location 
 ,dea.date) AS RollingPeopleVaccinated
 --,(RollingPeopleVaccinated/dea.population)*100
FROM CovidDeaths dea
JOIN CovidVaccinations vac 
    ON dea.location = vac.location 
    AND dea.date = vac.date
WHERE dea.continent is not null
ORDER BY 2,3
```

However, when I execute that, I get the following

```
The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled.
```

when I search about it , it shows that's a parser bug that exists only in SQL Server 2008 but my server is Microsoft SQL SERVER 2019 ?!

Comment: What compatability level is your database in?

Comment: it is SQL Server 2008 (100) and the newest option :l , so is better to upgrade the SQL server 2008 to 2012 then 2016 or  to change the compatibility level for the entire server ?

Comment: Well, you said in the question that you're using SQL Server 2019 right?  So your option would then to update the compatability level.